# Can you stream the camera live through Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, camera, live-streaming

I want to stream the camera connected to Windows in real time on Android. I'm looking for a way other than wifi because I'll use it outdoors.

I thought of Bluetooth. Can I stream videos using Bluetooth? How do you use vdp among Bluetooth profiles?

If there is a better way than Bluetooth, please let me know.

Thank you and I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: No, Bluetooth isn't possible.  There isn't enough bandwidth for video, and the communication distance is much smaller than WiFi.  Are you wanting to use mobile data and stream this over the internet?

Comment: @Brad It would be nice to do it online, but there will be a problem of accessing public IP outdoors.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth does not work well for long distances, and if you wish to go outdoors (assuming your computer is in the house), streaming a live camera feed probably will not work effectively.

I suggest using [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/) or [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en) to connect to your computer which should have the camera window open. Both TeamViewer and AnyDesk are free for personal use. But this is assuming that you have a data connection on your Android. Or perhaps your wifi stretches into your backyard (unlikely).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I lacked explanation.
Windows (Latte Panda) and Android communicate at a distance of about 50cm.
So I'm looking for a way that's not remote access.